# Checkboxes list values in a form

Tags: angular, checkbox

I'm new to Angular 2 so I'll need your advice to achieve development
I'm working on a create/update form component. I have a checkbox list with default values (checked or not, it depends about a service).
Here is my code :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-campaign',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="campaignForm" (ngSubmit)="saveCampaign()" novalidate>
    <label for="formations">Formations</label>
    <ul *ngFor="let formation of formations">
      <li>
        <label>
          <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            [attr.checked]="formation.formationCochee == 1 ? 'checked' : null">
            {{formation.formation}}
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input 
      type="submit" 
      class="btn btn-primary" 
      value="Save" 
      [disabled]="campaignForm.invalid"/>
  </form
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./campaign.component.css'],
  providers: [CampaignService, FormationService]
})
export class CampaignComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number = 0;
  campaignForm: FormGroup;        
  title: string = "New campaign";
  errorMessage: any;
  formations: Formation[];

  constructor(
    private _fb: FormBuilder,
    private _campaignService : CampaignService,
    private _formationService: FormationService
    ) { 
      this.campaignForm = this._fb.group({  
        id: ''
        , description: ["", Validators.required]
        // ...
      });

      if (this._avRoute.snapshot.params["id"]) {
        this.id = parseInt( this._avRoute.snapshot.params["id"]);
      }
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    // Case : Update Form
    if(this.id > 0){ 
      this.title = 'Update';    
      this._formationService.selectedFormations(this.id)
      .subscribe(formations =>
        this.formations=formations['records']
      );
    } 
    // Case : Create Form
    else {
      this._formationService.listActiveFormations()
      .subscribe(formations =>
        this.formations=formations['records']
      );
    }
  }

  saveCampaign(){ 
    this._campaignService.saveCampaign(this.campaignForm.value)
    .subscribe(campaign => {
        this._router.navigate(['campaigns']);
     }, error => this.errorMessage = error )
  }
}
```

My questions :

- How can I set my default datas for my checkboxes list ?
- Is it possible to update these defaults values when the user check or uncheck the boxes ?
- Is a FormArray a good option to resolve my problem ?
- And please, let me know if you seeing bads habits in my code, I don't have any returns about it ... I'm asking a lot but I'm stucked for a while now ...

*PS: I'm trying to do it without existing component to improve my angular2 skills.*

Thx for yours advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `FormArray` for this case, to iterate the data in `formations` and push each object as a `FormGroup` to a `FormArray` in your form.

Or, you could just on submit of form, populate your `FormArray` with the values of `formations`.

Going with the latter option, you would, just like you have, iterate the array and display the checkboxes. You can instead of `[attr.checked]` use `[(ngModel)]` instead. With that, you need to add `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}` as this is a reactive form. So your list should look like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let formation of formations">
    <label>
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        [(ngModel)]="formation.formationCochee"
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        {{formation.formation}}
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When you create the form, add an empty `FormArray` for your array:

```ts
this.campaignForm = this.fb.group({
  formations: this.fb.array([])
});
```

Then when you submit the form you can replace that empty `FormArray` with your `formations`:

```ts
saveCampaign(){ 
  this.campaignForm.setControl('formations', this.fb.array(this.formations))
  this._campaignService.saveCampaign(this.campaignForm.value)
    .subscribe(campaign => {
       this._router.navigate(['campaigns']);
    }, error => this.errorMessage = error )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- *How can I set my default datas for my checkboxes list ?*

  ```
   [attr.checked]="formation.formationCochee">
  ```

In JS, you have **truthy** and **falsy** values. For instance, `1` is a truthy value, which is means `is true`. Angular will understand what you want to do, and check the checkbox for you.

- *Is it possible to update these defaults values when the user check or uncheck the boxes ?*

**No**. If the user updates the default value, then it's not the default value anymore ! Otherwise i didn't get your question, maybe yo ucould rephrase it ?

- *Is a FormArray a good option to resolve my problem ?*

What is your issue exactly ? You didn't specify any issue, you only asked questions ...

- *And please, let me know if you seeing bads habits in my code*

  `<ul *ngFor="let formation of formations">`

You should instead repeat on the `li` tag : the ul/ol tag is only the **list container**, while `li` is the **list item**.

```
<label>
      <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        [attr.checked]="formation.formationCochee == 1 ? 'checked' : null">
        {{formation.formation}}
    </label>
```

The label should **not** contain the input. The label is meant to describe the input, which means that it is able to interact with the input with the `for` attribute.